# What script does hide parent menu items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If you click some menu item with nested sumbmenu at this [site](http://www.antilopagold.su) at the top horizontal navbar(bootstrap 3) and then click another main menu item (also having nested submenu items) you will see that the first parent menu item will disappear. 
Please help me find what script do this and explain how you found it. I was trying to debug by setting breakpoint in a custom.js by means of Chrome developer tools but it didn't help me, i have a small knowledges and experience with debugging JS

Comment: i've found such callstack http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0511/h_1462979952_5199467_d125230049.jpg the last Element.implement.setStyle function in mootools-core.js is hiding menu items. I think that I have to prevent the spread of some event. But what is this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Element.implement.setStyle function in mootools-core.js hides menu items